# Google Bot is not able to read my css and js even after allowing in Robot.txt

Tags: wordpress, indexing, robots.txt

Google bot is not able to read my css and js even after I have allowed it in robot.txt file.
The site is build in Wordpress.
Below is my robot.txt file.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /timeclock/
Disallow: /staging/

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /*.css$

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: / 
Allow: /*.css$

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /
Allow: /*.css$

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Allow: /* .js* 
Allow: /* .css*
```

Comment: I think you don't need use `Allow: /* .js*` `Allow: /* .css*` try to put out * and write `Allow: /.css*`
this command * usually it's for make an Note open by /* and close by */
So you can see you have to delete and after i think work.

Answer (score 0):

Like i have write in the comment, you don't need unse /* this is use for add a note, and open by /* and close by */. try to change your code in this way and see if work:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /timeclock/
Disallow: /staging/

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /.css$

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: / 
Allow: /.css$

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /
Allow: /.css$

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Allow: /.js 
Allow: /.css
```

Comment: But why you want the google read you css? if you have some content inside google will read from html.